# GNU screen source a custom bashrc file for new windows

Tags: gnu-screen

At the office, we have a shared user we use half the time. I'm trying to get screen to automatically load a custom bashrc file that I created for myself when using the shared user. So far I have this which works well:

alias screen='screen -d -R -S redhar -c /home/redhar/.screenrc bash -rcfile '\''/home/goldenuser/.bashrc_redhar'\'''

This works well for the very first window it creates. The problem comes when I create a new window. Is there anyway to get a newly created window to automatically use the same rcfile?

So far I have considered the following option, but I'm looking for a more streamlined solution along the lines of a missing GNU screen config option I overlooked or something. My proposed solution:

In regular .bashrc which gets loaded automatically:

```
if [[ $SCREENFLAG == "REDHAR" ]]
then
    . /home/goldenuser/.bashrc_redhar
    exit
fi
```

Set alias to:

`alias screen='SCREENFLAG=REDHAR screen -d -R -S redhar -c /home/redhar/.screenrc bash -rcfile '\''/home/goldenuser/.bashrc_redhar'\'''`

Comment: You can check the value of the `TERM` environment variable - it is typically set to `screen` within a `screen` session, where outside it would be `vt100`, `xterm` or something else...

Comment: I considered that, but since it's a shared user, multiple people might use screen.

Comment: Ah, so you want it to only change behavior for *you* when you are using `screen`, not for everyone else... That's a bit trickier... But I suppose you could set a different environment variable (one that nobody else would ever set) before you start `screen`, and your `.bashrc` check for the existence of that variable...

Comment: @twalberg Yup, as you can see in my original post, that's exactly what I'm proposing. I'm just wondering if I missed an easier solution preferably something built into screen like a configuration option in screenrc that will automatically run a command for each new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered the solution is to create a file with

```
bash -rcfile /home/goldenuser/.bashrc_redhar
```

then set your shell command in .screenrc to it

```
shell='<path to file created above>'
```

Comment: Actually, it works like `shell /home/goldenuser/.bashrc_redhar` with .bashrc_redhar being a common executable script

Comment: This changes $SHELL variable, therefore if there a script to check $SHELL variable, it makes problem. It currently annoy me.